# mail() php : without sender works, with sender doesn't works

Tags: php, email, sender

I have a contact form, with mail() function.
For a long time it worked correctly. Suddenly now it doesn't work.
I have checked, but all is correct. But if I delete the sender parameter, it works, with sender parameters it doesn't work:

```
mail($destinatario_1,$oggetto_1,$messaggio_1,'');
```

WORKS

Instead:

```
mail($destinatario_1,$oggetto_1,$messaggio_1,'From: "My Name" <thisisanexample@gmail.com> \r\n');
```

Thanks

Comment: `\r\n` only works like you want inside double quotes, not single ones.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is with your servers mail settings. If the code has not changed, then the code cannot be blamed.

Comment: Error logs? Spam filter? SPF Records change?

Comment: My strong recommendation is to avoid using PHP's built-in `mail()` function at all costs. It is unreliable, difficult to work with, lacking features, and often doesn't provide any useful info about why an email hasn't been sent. Instead, I suggest using a well-written mailer class such as [phpMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
mail($destinatario_1, $oggetto_1, $messaggio_1, "From: My Name <thisisanexample@gmail.com>");
```

Note that I leave our the `\r\n` which should just be `\n` on most servers and must be in double quotes not single quotes, and "My Name" shouldn't be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Mail servers can be configured to not accept mail when certain information is set. The PHP `mail()` function more or less directly talks to the local mail server and passes the mail to it. Whether the mail server accepts it or not is not really part of the communication and cannot be detected by a PHP script.

Consult your web hosting company to find out if there are any restrictions.